# WKWebView setContentOffset does not work with animated = false: no scrolling occurs

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am attempting to create an EPUB reader. Since the chapters in an EPUB are represented as whole HTML files with no page breaks, I will display one page at a time in a `WKWebView`, loading the string with `loadHTMLString`. Then, when the user swipes to the next page of the `UIPageViewController`, I will make a new `WKWebView` and scroll down a page using the `setContentOffset` method. However, the `setContentOffset` method has no effect on the displayed content. tldr - how can I tell when this `setContentOffset` method is safe to call?

Here is my page view controller:

```swift
class MyPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    var page = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        dataSource = self
        delegate = self
        
        setViewControllers([Page(page: 0)], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return Page(page: page + 1)
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        if completed {
            page += 1
        }
   }
}
```

and here is my `Page` class:

```swift
class Page: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {
    var page: Int
    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    let testString = "<h1>00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</h1><br><h1>11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</h1><br><h1>22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222</h1><br><h1>33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333</h1><br><h1>44444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444</h1><br><h1>55555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555</h1><br><h1>66666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666</h1><br><h1>77777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777</h1><br><h1>88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888</h1><br><h1>99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999</h1>"

    init(page: Int) {
        self.page = page
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        
        view.addSubview(webView)
        
        load()
    }
    
    func load() {
        webView.loadHTMLString(testString, baseURL: nil)
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.scroll()
    }
    
    func scroll() {
        let scrollPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100 * CGFloat(page))
        webView.scrollView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: false)
    }
}
```

I want the scroll to be instantaneous so that the user cannot tell it is scrolling, hence the `animated: false`. However, this simply does not change the view in any way. If I use `animated: true` it works fine, and if I wrap `self.scroll()` in a `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1)` it works as well. But the user can see a bit of a jarring scroll if I do this. I have tried calling `.setNeedsLayout()` and `.layoutIfNeeded()` to no avail; the view still does not change.

So clearly there is something that is not ready to scroll the webView, even after the `didFinish` delegate method is called. How can I tell when this `webView` is actually ready to scroll? Or is there another reason that `animated: false` is not working?

Comment: Scrolling requires size and content. I would presume it can't scroll until it has finished loading and when initial layout has finished. Where is your code that detects that? At the very least `viewDidLoad` is way too early.

Comment: @matt How can you detect when initial layout has finished? I tried putting `load()` into `viewDidAppear`; you can tell the scrollView's contentSize is correct with `print(webView.scrollView.contentSize)`, but there is still no visual change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching the issue, I came to a similar conclusion as https://stackoverflow.com/a/76145772/8010366. It appears that there is an issue with the initial scrolling.

---

However, if you still need to manually scroll without the animation, you can use the following low-level code:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    let yOffset = 20 * page
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollTop = \(100 * yOffset)")
}
```

This executes a JavaScript code to scroll the HTML document. Additionally, you should add more content to enable scrolling.

---

References:

- [evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript)
- [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)

Answer (score 1):

Tldr; I don't have an actual answer, but here is some more info

Trying to figure out what is going on, I made de Page class the delegate for the webiew scrollView. When doing that, you can see something weird happen when putting a print in the delegates `scrollViewDidScroll` event:

```swift
onSetContentOffset
didScroll (0.0, 100.0)
didScroll (0.0, 0.0)
didScroll (0.0, -102.0)
didScroll (0.0, 0.0)
didScroll (0.0, 518.3333333333334)
didScroll (0.0, 398.0)
didScroll (0.0, 0.0)
```

initially the offset *does* get set to 100, but then something weird happens and the offset goes all over the place before eventually going back to 0.

A similiar thing seems to happen if you set animated to `true`, but then *because* it is animated it gets fixed automatically

```swift
onSetContentOffset
didScroll (0.0, -118.0)
didScroll (0.0, 0.0)
didScroll (0.0, 0.6666666666666666)
didScroll (0.0, 0.0)
didScroll (0.0, 518.3333333333334)
didScroll (0.0, 398.0)
didScroll (0.0, 0.0)
didScroll (0.0, 2.0)
didScroll (0.0, 5.666666666666667)
didScroll (0.0, 10.333333333333334)
didScroll (0.0, 16.333333333333332)
didScroll (0.0, 23.666666666666668)
didScroll (0.0, 31.333333333333332)
didScroll (0.0, 39.666666666666664)
didScroll (0.0, 48.333333333333336)
didScroll (0.0, 57.0)
didScroll (0.0, 65.66666666666667)
didScroll (0.0, 73.66666666666667)
didScroll (0.0, 80.66666666666667)
didScroll (0.0, 87.0)
didScroll (0.0, 92.0)
didScroll (0.0, 96.0)
didScroll (0.0, 98.33333333333333)
didScroll (0.0, 99.33333333333333)
```

I don't actually know what causes this and don't have time to investigate further. My best advice is to accept the animated scroll or delaying it for now. Perhaps you could hide the webView behind a loading view until everything is loaded if you really don't want people to see the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for doing the research! That is weird, I'll try looking into it further. Any idea if the setContentOffset internals are available somewhere?